# MailCore2, fetch only UNREAD messages, or know which ones are UNREAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I am able to fetch all messages using `fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:`, however, message.flags all return 0 when some messages are unread, most are read and some are starred.

```
MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];
[fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages)
{
    if ( ! error )  {
        for ( MCOIMAPMessage * message_ in fetchedMessages )  {
           // I only want UNREAD messages.
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using `if ( message_.flags & MCOMessageFlagSeen )` but still, all flags return as **0**.

What is the proper way to see if the message is **UNREAD**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, you need to also include the kind request for flags: `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags`.

```
MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders|MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags;
```

Then, look for the unread flag:

```
for ( MCOIMAPMessage * message_ in fetchedMessages )  {
    if ( message_.flags == 0 ) {
        // I have a suspicion that this is not the correct
        // way to do this, but it seems to work the way I need.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 0 or better as below, which is 0 too, but who knows if they decide to change it to something else later:

```
if(message_.flags == MCOMessageFlagNone)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CMMessageSession *session = [CMessageManager shareManager].session;
MCOIMAPSession *imapSession = [session imapSession];
MCOIMAPFolderStatusOperation *folderOpera = [imapSession folderStatusOperation:folder];
if (!folderOpera) {
    NSLog(@"获取imap邮箱状态失败");
    [self fetchUnReadCountFromDB:folder complete:complete];
    return;
}

[folderOpera start:^(NSError * _Nullable error, MCOIMAPFolderStatus * _Nullable status) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"获取imap邮箱状态失败: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        [self fetchUnReadCountFromDB:folder complete:complete];
        return;
    }
    
    NSInteger count = status.unseenCount;
    if (complete) {
        complete(folder, count);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).